# Why can't I initialize a loop with i = -1?

Tags: c

I was learning about loops when I stumbled upon this thing I don't understand.

In this code, if I enter in the for loop, `i = 0`, it works as intended, if I write "dog", I get 3 a's, but if I write `i = -1`, I don't get input at all, shouldn't give me an extra a?

Can't I start the `i` value wherever I want?

```
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        char string[10];

        scanf("%s", string);

        void changestring (char *newstring) {
                for (int i=0; i < strlen(newstring); i++) {
                        printf("a");
                }
        }
        changestring(string);
}
```

Comment: `strlen()` returns an *unsigned* value. Comparing an int with an unsigned value forces a conversion of the int. `(unsigned)-1 == 0xffffffff` and `0xffffffff > strlen(whatever)`

Comment: and don't use strlen inside a loop, it'll be called again and again which is very inefficient. Store the length in a variable instead

Comment: Try `i < strlen(newstring)` --> `i < 0 || (unsigned)i < strlen(newstring)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's rewrite your code a little bit, for the sake of removing some confusion (because to the uninitiated there are few things going on here, that might seem similar, but are not).

> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void print_as_according_to_strlen(char *n) {
>     for (int i=0; i < strlen(newstring); i++) {
>         printf("a");
>     }
> }
> ```

There, this is the relevant part. If you look at the definition of `strlen` you'll see, that it returns a value of type `size_t`

> ```
> size_t strlen(const char *s);
> ```
>
> Return the length of the string s.

`size_t` is an *unsigned* type. C and C++ have certain rules by which integer values are implicited converted to a "common" type when used together in an operation. These are the so called *"integer promotion rules"* – those are important to know, and you absolutely must learn them.

One of those rules is, that if you make a *signed* integer "interact" with an *unsigned* integer, the promoted type will be *unsigned* as well. And of course if you attempt to promote a negative value to an unsigned type, the result will be something different.

Now with C things become tricky here, because there are some (actually the majority of cases) where attempting to do that invokes *undefined behavior*, i.e. anything may happen. There are however a few exceptions, where it's actually well behaved (for example if you have two *unsigned* variables `unsigned a = 3` and `unsigned b = 5` the result of the operation `a-b` is actually a well defined value, because unsigned overflow is well defined, and the result is `UINT_MAX - (b-a)`).

The bottom line for you is: You must rewrite your code so that the comparison promotes to either a signed comparison, or instead of starting from `-1`, go to `strlen(…)+1`. Instead of using an `int` I suggest you use a `ptrdiff_t` instead, because the size of an int may, or may not, be sufficient to hold the result of `strlen`. And by happenstance (not of C, but how modern OSs manage memory) `strlen` will never return a value that could overflow `ptrdiff_t`

```
ptrdiff_t len = strlen(newstring);
for(ptrdiff_t i=-1; i < len ; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters nested function definitions is not a C standard feature. You should defined the function outside main.

As for your question then in this expression

```
i < strlen(newstring)
```

the compiler determinates the common type of the operands of the operator < using the usual arithmetic conversions of the operands.

The returned type of the function `strlen` is `size_t` that is an unsigned type that has the conversion rank higher or equal to the rank of the type int. SO the expression i is converted to the unsigned type size_t preserving its bits. As a result you get a very big unsigned value that is gretaer than the value returned by the function strlen and the caondition evaluates to false.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = -1;

    printf( "i = %i, ( size_t )i = %zu\n", i, ( size_t  ) i );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
i = -1, ( size_t )i = 18446744073709551615
```